# Detecting contact of a SKSpritenode with many SKSpritenodes Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, skphysicsbody

I need to detect contact in my project, but I have 9 squares that i want to detect contact with. Is there a way to detect contact without creating 9 different physics bodies or something like an array of physics bodies. Also, every time the circle touches a square, that square will turn color. I want to do this with something like an array like this:

```
for i in 1...9{
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.square[i] && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.circle || firstBody.categoryBitMask == 
PhysicsCategory.circle && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.square[i] {

    squares[i].node.color = squares[i].targetColor
    //this is my array of structs containing the skspritenodes
    squares[i].colorBlendFactor = 1.0


}
}
```

I have tried making 9 physics bodies but i got a lot of errors. This is what I have done so far.

```
import SpriteKit

var squares = Array<square>()
var positions = Array<CGPoint>()
var squareUnit = CGFloat()
var rows = Array<CGFloat>()
var columbs = Array<CGFloat>()
var circle = SKSpriteNode()
var physics = Array<UInt32>()

struct PhysicsCategory{

static let circle : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
static let square1 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let square2 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
static let square3 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
static let square4 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
static let square5 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
static let square6 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 6
static let square7 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 7
static let square8 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 8
static let square9 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 9






}

struct square{

var startColor = UIColor()
var middleColor = UIColor()
var targetColor = UIColor()
var has3Colors = Bool()
var permanent = Bool()
var node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Square")
var currentState = Int()




}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        createScene()

       }

    func createScene(){
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    createSquares()
    createCircles()


}


func createCircles(){

    circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
    circle.size.width = squares[1].node.size.width * 0.9
    circle.size.height = squares[1].node.size.height * 0.9
    circle.position = squares[4].node.position
    circle.color = UIColor.blue
    circle.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    circle.zPosition = 10
    circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: circle.frame.width / 2)
    circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.circle
    circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    circle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square1
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square2
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square3
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square4
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square5
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square6
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square7
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square8
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square9

        self.addChild(circle)



}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB


       }


func createSquares(){
    for i in 1...9{

       // squares[i].currentState = 1

    }
    squareUnit = self.frame.width / 4



    columbs = [squareUnit / 4 + squareUnit/2, self.frame.width/2,self.frame.width - squareUnit / 4 - squareUnit / 2]
    rows = [squareUnit / 4 + squareUnit/2, self.frame.width/2,self.frame.width - squareUnit / 4 - squareUnit / 2]
    for row in rows{
        for columb in columbs{

          positions.append(CGPoint(x: columb, y: row))

        }


    }

    squares = (0...8).map { _ in square() }

    for i in (0...8){


        squares[i].node.position = positions[i]
        squares[i].node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: squares[i].node.size )
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false



    }
    for square in squares {

        square.node.size = CGSize(width: squareUnit, height: squareUnit)
        square.node.color = UIColor.white
    }

    squares.forEach { self.addChild($0.node) }

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {



        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        circle.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y), duration: 0.2))


    }

}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out i just create 9 physics bodies and then add them all to an array of UInt32 and assign them each to each node.

```
var physics = Array<UInt32>()



struct PhysicsCategory{

    static let square1 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let square2 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let square3 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    static let square4 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    static let square5 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
    static let square6 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 6
    static let square7 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 7
    static let square8 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 8
    static let square9 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 9
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square1)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square2)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square3)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square4)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square5)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square6)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square7)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square8)
    physics.append(PhysicsCategory.square9)


   for i in (0...8){

        squares[i].node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: squares[i].node.size )
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physics[i]
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Circle
        squares[i].node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


    }

}
```